# How do I output the results of a LINQ command to a text file?

Tags: c#, string, output

```
 var arrResults = Array1.Join(Array2, x => x.ID, x => x.ID, (first, second) => new
            {
                IDRecord = first.ID,
                Count1 = first.Count,
                Count2 = second.Count,
            })
            .OrderBy(item => item.IDRecord).ToArray(); 

            // bind & display results in datagrid
            dataGridView1.DataSource = arrResults;
```

My above code does exactly what I want it to, and shows the results in a dataGrid control.  Now, I'd like to export the results to a text file, C:\output.txt, instead.  How do I do this?

My previous attempts usually involve getting errors that say "cannot convert from 'string' to System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First convert the results to strings:

```
var lines = arrResults.Select(record => 
    record.ID + " " + record.Count1 + " " + record.Count2);//todo fix formatting
```

Then write them all to a file.

```
File.WriteAllLines("file.txt", lines);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `System.IO.Streamwriter` to write to file

```
using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\output.txt")){
   foreach(var s in arrResults)
       sw.WriteLine(s);

}
```

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for reference.